# Override Twenty Eleven Theme Option Link Color Style

Tags: wordpress

I am attempting to override the function (in an upgrade safe manner)

```
twentyeleven_print_link_color_style
```

which is found on line 378 of wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/inc/theme-options.php

I tried the following in my child themes functions.php, but twentyeleven_print_link_color_style is still firing (I can see the css it is outputting).

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'goodbye_internal_style_sheet' );
function goodbye_internal_style_sheet() {
    remove_filter( 'wp_head', 'twentyeleven_print_link_color_style' );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_action( 'init', 'goodbye_internal_style_sheet' );
function goodbye_internal_style_sheet() {
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'twentyeleven_print_link_color_style' );
}
```

- needed remove_filter instead of action
- was hooking to wrong action with add_action